# Oracle docker container not working properly on Mac M1 BigSur

Tags: oracle, docker, kubernetes, backend, devops

I was recently trying to create a docker container and connect it with my SQLDeveloper but I started facing some strange issues.
I downloaded the docker image using below pull request:

```
docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
```

then I started the container from my docker-desktop using port 1521. The container started with a warning.

[image]

terminal message:

```
docker run -d -it -p 1521:1521 --name oracle store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
5ea14c118397ce7ef2880786ac1fac061e8c92f9b09070edffe365653dcc03af
```

Now when I try connect to db using below command :

```
docker exec -it 5ea14c118397 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
SQL> connect sys as sysdba;
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

it shows this message, PASSWORD I USE IS Oradoc_db1.

Now after seeing some suggestions I tried using the below command for connecting to sqlplus:

```
 docker exec -it f888fa9d0247 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus / as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Sep 6 06:15:58 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

I also tried changing permissions of oracle file in $ORACLE_HOME as well for execution permissions as well but it didn't work.

Please help me out as I am stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: have you tried running the sqlplus command as follows? `sqlplus / as sysdba`. the message is probably because the host and container CPU architectures don't match and docker is using an emulation layer that might cause performance issues and other general issues

Comment: Have you tried adding `--platform linux/amd64` as an option on your `docker run` command?

Comment: Hi @Noam, I have tried running sqlplus / as sysdba but it shows the same error as you can see in the description. I have added the command snippet.

Comment: @harshitsrivastava have you tried any of the proposed solutions in [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12547_tns_lost_contact.htm) article?

Comment: Hi @HansKilian I have tried the above option as provided --plateform linux/amd64 but it starts and then exits with logs as below:


`The database is ready for use .

/usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/alert_ORCL.log' for reading: No such file or directory


/usr/bin/tail: no files remaining`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. Oracle Database is not supported on ARM processors, only Intel. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814
2. Oracle Database Docker images are only supported with Oracle Linux 7 or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 as the host OS. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

> Oracle Database ... is supported for Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7. For more details please see My Oracle Support note: **Oracle Support for Database Running on Docker (Doc ID 2216342.1)**

The referenced My Oracle Support Doc ID goes on to say that the database binaries in their Docker image are built specifically for Oracle Linux hosts, and will also work on Red Hat. That's it.

Linux being what it is (flexible), lots of people have gotten the images to run on other flavors like Ubuntu with a bit of creativity, but only on x86 processors and even then the results are not guaranteed by Oracle: you won't be able to get support or practical advice when (and it's always *when*, not *if* in IT) things don't work as expected. You might not even be able to *tell* when things aren't working as they should. This is a case where creativity is not particularly rewarded; if you want it to work and get meaningful help, my advice is to use the *supported* hardware architecture and operating system version. Anything else is a complete gamble.

Answer (score -1):

I think i will answer my own question and its similar to the accepted answer.

As the oracle db is very large in size and is very complex to handle and maintain on different systems like mac and all, therefore, its recommended to use the docker mentioned system configurations for running the docker container on your system.

I have used `MariaDB` and have also tried `MongoDB (NoSQL)` instead of using `oracle` as these are very much light and don't need strict configurations to run and they ran in no time. I could easily connect both of them with `SQLDeveloper(MariaDB)` and `MongoDB` compass`(MongoDB)`.
There are some custom oracle light weight versions as well but they are not very full proof to work on your system.